Read query locking the insertion of a new record on a table with error - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
I have a stored procedure that runs every one hour to generate a summary of the transactions that happened in the service. The stored procedure reads the data from a table called transaction_log and populates(insert or updates rows) another table called transaction_log_summary. There is no connection between the tables on a constraint level, ie no foreign key references etc. But for some reason when the stored procedure runs for the first time in a day and if a new insert query is also executed on the transaction_log at the same time, the insert statement failes with Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction error. The default isolation level used here is REPEATABLE READ (innoDB). How can a read operation lock the table from new rows being inserted?
Sharing the stored procedure and the related code below.
Function used to update the entries in the summary table
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE func_update_summary(IN date_param DATE, IN last_summary_index BIGINT)
BEGIN
    -- Update the summary for the input date with logs having newer ids 
        UPDATE transaction_log_summary tls
        JOIN (
            SELECT 
                DATE(created_at) AS date,
                SUM(CASE WHEN channel = 'NATS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS channel_NATS,
                SUM(CASE WHEN channel = 'SQS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS channel_SQS,
                SUM(CASE WHEN channel = 'API' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS channel_API,
                SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status_SUCCESS,
                SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'FAILURE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status_FAILURE,
                SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'SKIPPED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status_SKIPPED,
                MAX(id) AS last_transaction_log_index
            FROM 
                transaction_log
            WHERE
                DATE(created_at) = date_param
                AND id > last_summary_index
            GROUP BY 
                DATE(created_at)
        ) AS temp ON tls.date = temp.date
        SET 
            tls.channel_NATS = tls.channel_NATS + temp.channel_NATS,
            tls.channel_SQS = tls.channel_SQS + temp.channel_SQS,
            tls.channel_API = tls.channel_API + temp.channel_API,
            tls.status_SUCCESS = tls.status_SUCCESS + temp.status_SUCCESS,
            tls.status_FAILURE = tls.status_FAILURE + temp.status_FAILURE,
            tls.status_SKIPPED = tls.status_SKIPPED + temp.status_SKIPPED,
            tls.last_transaction_log_index = temp.last_transaction_log_index
        WHERE
            tls.date = date_param;
END//

DELIMITER ;

Stored procedure that performs date checks and updates the values using the above function
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE proc_update_transaction_log_summary()
BEGIN
    DECLARE present_date DATE;
    DECLARE last_summary_date DATE;
    DECLARE last_summary_index BIGINT;
    DECLARE last_log_index BIGINT;
    DECLARE has_records INT;

    DECLARE error_code INT;
    DECLARE error_msg VARCHAR(255);

    DECLARE lock_acquired INT DEFAULT 0;

    -- Try to acquire the named lock immediately
    SET lock_acquired = GET_LOCK('update_summary_lock', 0); -- 0 means try to acquire immediately
    
    IF lock_acquired = 1 THEN
        BEGIN
            DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
            BEGIN
                GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 error_code = MYSQL_ERRNO, error_msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
                ROLLBACK;
                SELECT CONCAT('Error ', error_code, ': ', error_msg);
                DO RELEASE_LOCK('update_summary_lock');
            END;

            START TRANSACTION;
            
            SET present_date = CURDATE();
            
            -- Get the last index and date from transaction_log_summary table
            SELECT last_transaction_log_index, date INTO last_summary_index, last_summary_date
            FROM transaction_log_summary
            ORDER BY date DESC
            LIMIT 1;

            -- If last summary date is less than current date, update the summary
            IF last_summary_date < present_date THEN
                BEGIN
                    -- Get the last index from the transaction log for the last_summary_date
                    SELECT MAX(id) INTO last_log_index FROM transaction_log 
                    WHERE DATE(created_at) = last_summary_date;

                    IF last_log_index > last_summary_index THEN
                        CALL func_update_summary(last_summary_date, last_summary_index);
                    END IF;
                    
                    -- Check if there are records for the present date
                    SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM transaction_log WHERE DATE(created_at) =
                    CURRENT_DATE LIMIT 1) INTO has_records;

                    IF has_records THEN
                        
                        -- Insert new record in the summary table for the current date
                        INSERT INTO transaction_log_summary (date, channel_NATS, channel_SQS, channel_API, status_SUCCESS, status_FAILURE, status_SKIPPED, last_transaction_log_index)
                        SELECT present_date,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN channel = 'NATS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS channel_NATS,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN channel = 'SQS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS channel_SQS,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN channel = 'API' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS channel_API,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status_SUCCESS,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'FAILURE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status_FAILURE,
                            SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'SKIPPED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status_SKIPPED,
                            MAX(id) AS last_transaction_log_index
                        FROM transaction_log
                        WHERE DATE(created_at) = present_date;

                    ELSE
                        -- Insert new record in the summary table for the present date with last index from previous day
                        INSERT INTO transaction_log_summary (date,  last_transaction_log_index)
                        SELECT present_date, MAX(id) AS last_transaction_log_index
                        FROM transaction_log;

                    END IF;
                END;
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    -- Get the last index from the transaction log for the last_summary_date
                    SELECT MAX(id) INTO last_log_index FROM transaction_log 
                    WHERE DATE(created_at) = present_date;
                    
                    -- Check if there are new entries in the log table
                    IF last_log_index > last_summary_index THEN
                        CALL func_update_summary(present_date, last_summary_index);
                    END IF;
                END;
            END IF;
            
            COMMIT;
            SELECT ''; -- empty msg utilised by app layer to identify successful end of execution
            DO RELEASE_LOCK('update_summary_lock');
        END;
    END IF;

END//

DELIMITER ;

Event scheduled to execute the procedure every one hour
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT job_update_transaction_log_summary
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 HOUR
DO
BEGIN
    CALL proc_update_transaction_log_summary();
END//
DELIMITER ;

Also, observed that in one of the deployment environment where the stored procedures isolation level was updated as READ COMMITTED, we didnt face the issue.
ie within the stored procedure, before the transaction is started, we set the isolation level.
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

But how come a read operation cause this issue? And did this setting of the distinct isolation level for stored procedure really solve the issue or will we encounter the issue in a different use case?

Any read query executed as part of a DML statement (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) is implicitly a locking read.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html says:

INSERT INTO T SELECT ... FROM S WHERE ... sets an exclusive index
record lock (without a gap lock) on each row inserted into T. If the
transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED, InnoDB does the search
on S as a consistent read (no locks). Otherwise, InnoDB sets shared
next-key locks on rows from S. InnoDB has to set locks in the latter
case: During roll-forward recovery using a statement-based binary log,
every SQL statement must be executed in exactly the same way it was
done originally.
CREATE TABLE ... SELECT ... performs the SELECT with shared next-key
locks or as a consistent read, as for INSERT ... SELECT.
When a SELECT is used in the constructs REPLACE INTO t SELECT ... FROM s WHERE ... or UPDATE t ... WHERE col IN (SELECT ... FROM s ...),
InnoDB sets shared next-key locks on rows from table s.

That manual page doesn't list the cases explicitly, but this also affects cases like:
SELECT ... INTO @var;

SET @var = (SELECT ...);

UPDATE ... JOIN (SELECT...)

Foreign key checks

SELECT inside a DML trigger

As you discovered, using READ COMMITTED eliminates the need to create those implicit locks, and this is what the manual says.

Re your comments:
These statements may help clarify:

Read queries (i.e. a SELECT statement that is not part of another DML statement) don't acquire row locks in any transaction isolation level.

Read queries that are part of a DML statement (like the subquery in your UPDATE statement), or which set variables, do acquire shared row locks if you use REPEATABLE READ, but do not acquire row locks if you use READ COMMITTED.

Row locks last only until the end of the transaction, not the procedure. A procedure may start and commit one or more transactions. Or a procedure may not commit, so the transaction remains active after the procedure returns.

User-level locks acquired with GET_LOCK() are not the same as row locks. These are implemented outside the InnoDB storage engine, and have nothing to do with transactions. These user-level locks are held until released with RELEASE_LOCK() or until your session ends. Again, this is not related to the procedure scope, and is not related to transaction isolation level.



New to this level of info on transactions in a DB. Read up on same and a summary of the scenario, to best of my knowledge would be as follows, even though a read is not supposed to block any new inserts, an implicit lock acquired during the operation caused blocking of new rows in the log table, mainly due to REPEATABLE READ, that forces the lock to be retained till the end of the transaction (here until SP execution completes). And when I make isolation level as READ COMMITTED, the locks are not retained till the end of SP execution, only till the read operation is completed.

And with this behavior do you see any scenario in the stored procedure where the calculation can go wrong, while deriving the summay of transaction logs with READ COMMITTED isolation level?

Lets say SELECT acquired shared locks as its part of INSERT or UPDATE statement. But shared locks shouldn't block the insertion of new rows into the log table right? Shared locks only block update or delete of the rows being read right? In my case, only inserts happen on the log table, while stored procedure reads the existing rows. Or is it like REPEATABLE READ wants to ensure that reads are consistent and hence block insert also
Also,in my case, entire stored procedure code is part of a single transaction (START TRANSACTION and COMMIT wraps the entire logic), could that also be a problem?

Read about gap locks and next-key locks. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks

Hi @Bill Karwin
Looks like the select query that was generating the summary was not utilizing the indexes, I was also wondering how the simple query was taking more than 50sec to complete. I tried explaning the current query and the one suggested by Rick, one utilised the index on created at where as the other didnt use any. Also, am reading upon the doc you suggested, looks really informative.

WHERE DATE(created_at) = date_param

is not sargable ,  If created_at is a DATE, then simply do created_at = date_param.  If it is a DATETIME, then
WHERE created_at >= date_param
  AND created_at  < date_param + INTERVAL 1 DAY

Similarly, it seems that
GROUP BY  DATE(created_at)

can be removed since only one date is involved.
These, plus other things smell like the 'wrong' way to do summarization; see Summary Tables
Of note, I would expect you to be using INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
lock_acquired, etc, worries me.  Is it possible for the proc to run for more than an hour?  If so, doesn't it mess up with with date_param sometimes being across midnight?  (The IODKU aluded to above solves that problem gracefully.)  Simply "remembering where you left off" should be a clue of how to avoid needing a transaction.

created_at is a dattime and the date_param is a date, which can be present day or the previous day, to account for the last transactions happened during the last and current execution of stored procedure,
lock_aquired is to avoid stored procedure running more than once, we have a summary api that fetches the summary, so on that api call also we trigger the stored procedure, hence wanted to avoid multiple sp triggers.

also along with the created at query change, shall we add the following to ensure the status column index is also considered, ie WHERE created_at >= date_param
AND created_at  < date_param + INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND status IN ('SUCCESS', 'FAILURE', 'SKIPPED');

Also, to clarify, the issue regarding the index not being used is not with the update in the function, as it uses ib > last_summary_index (here last_summary_index is an indexed column), but with the insert statement thats directly referred in the stored procedure right?

INSERT, itself, does not use any INDEX; SELECT in INSERT...SELECT... may use an index.

IN (...) AND datetime >... it too complex to efficiently use an index.  (Some index may help some.)

IODKU may avoid the present/previous day issue.  Getting rid of GET_LOCK is probably the key to your original problem.

GET_LOCK is utilzed to ensure that the stored procedure does't run more than once at any given time. How is that key to the initial problem? Also, I tried to execute the select query with DATE(created_at) and that was taking a lot of time irrespective of the amount of data in the table. So i was hoping index usage sorts my problem. And am only using datetime >= date_param AND date< (date_param + INTERVAL 1 DAY) in the updated query, not using IN (...) . modified att the DATE(created_at) to using the created_at >= ... AND created_at < ...

@midhundkumar - Just WHERE datetime >= date_param AND date< (date_param + INTERVAL 1 DAY), plus any index starting with datetime should be optimal.

and...  My goal is to speed up the query -- to minimize GET_LOCK time and to keep the query from interfering with things.
